# JQuery - Set dropdown values based on other dropdown value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have three dropdown values like below

As you can see, If one dropdown's value is not equals to "All", I need to set other dropdown values to "All". What is happening now is, if I change the first dropdown' value other values are setting properly, but when I change the second dropdown, first dropdown is not setting to "All". It is working in reverse order. After setting all values I need to send the variables as parameters to a function call.

```js
  var selActuals = $('#actuals_dropdown').val();
  var selBudget = $('#budget_dropdown').val();
  var selYTD = $('#ytd_dropdown').val();

  if (selActuals != "All") {
    $('#budget_dropdown').val("All");
    $('#ytd_dropdown').val("All");
  } else if (selBudget != "All") {
    $('#actuals_dropdown').val("All");
    $('#ytd_dropdown').val("All");
  } else if (selYTD != "All") {
    $('#actuals_dropdown').val("All");
    $('#budget_dropdown').val("All");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="region-block">
  <div class="lbl">Yearly Actuals:</div>
  <div class="ftr">
    <select id="actuals_dropdown" name="actuals_dropdown" style="width: 100%;">
      <option value="All">Sort By</option>
      <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
      <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="region-block">
  <div class="lbl">Yearly Budget:</div>
  <div class="ftr">
    <select id="budget_dropdown" name="budget_dropdown" style="width: 100%;">
      <option value="All">Sort By</option>
      <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
      <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="region-block">
  <div class="lbl">YTD:</div>
  <div class="ftr">
    <select id="ytd_dropdown" name="ytd_dropdown" style="width: 100%;">
      <option value="All">Sort By</option>
      <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
      <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your javascript is only running when the page first loads.  Do you realize there's no javascript executing after that? `$(document).ready()` runs one time when the page is ready.

Comment: Actually, whole code runs in a function which calls on every dropdown change.

Comment: Ah, I see you changed the post since my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand it correctly, you can do like this;
Give all select input a class name like 'drp-filter'

```js
$(function() {
  $('.drp-filter').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value != 'All') {
      $('.drp-filter').val('All')
      $(this).val(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="region-block">
  <div class="lbl">Yearly Actuals:</div>
  <div class="ftr">
    <select id="actuals_dropdown" name="actuals_dropdown" style="width: 100%;" class='drp-filter'>
      <option value="All">Sort By</option>
      <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
      <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="region-block">
  <div class="lbl">Yearly Budget:</div>
  <div class="ftr">
    <select id="budget_dropdown" name="budget_dropdown" style="width: 100%;" class='drp-filter'>
      <option value="All">Sort By</option>
      <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
      <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="region-block">
  <div class="lbl">YTD:</div>
  <div class="ftr">
    <select id="ytd_dropdown" name="ytd_dropdown" style="width: 100%;" class='drp-filter'>
      <option value="All">Sort By</option>
      <option value="DESC">DESC</option>
      <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```